# why does the c compiler automatically insert new line after pressing enter on scanf

Tags: c

Beginner here. so after i compile this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    printf("Enter a five digit number: ");

    int number;
    scanf("%d",&number);

    int reverse = 0;

    reverse = reverse+number%10*10000;
    number = number/10;

    reverse = reverse+number%10*1000;
        number = number/10;

    reverse = reverse+number%10*100;
        number = number/10;

    reverse = reverse+number%10*10;
        number = number/10;

    reverse = reverse+number%10;
        number = number/10;

    printf("Reverse number is: %d \n",reverse);

    return 0;
}
```

I get output as

```
Enter a five digit number: 12345
Reverse number is: 54321
```

problem is i have not used `\n` in the beginning of the last `printf()` so why does it automatically output a new line?

Comment: There's a lot of optimization you can do here to minimize the code, but `+=` is something you need to learn about first, as well as related operators like `/=` and so on.

Comment: compiler does not add anything.

Comment: Same reason the terminal displayed a `1` when you typed `1`. You're familiar with how hitting Enter creates a new line, right? You hit Enter multiple times when writing this code, and this post.

Answer (score 2):

When using the console *any input* will be echoed unless you suppress that using control codes. It's not the compiler doing this, it's your terminal.

If you run this a different way you get different output:

```
echo "12345" | ./digits
```

You get:

```
Enter a five digit number: Reverse number is: 54321
```

Where `digits` is your compiled executable.

Comment: You could also do this by causing your interactive input stream to close (^D twice on most terminals/shells for example) rather than pressing return.